# Login Password Does Not Save

Tags: login, security

The login password does not save when I login in ether Chrome or Safari (on Mac). I am running 2.7. This is a pain in the ass when I am developing, I need to login 25 times a day with my password.

On an older site I built last year it remembers my login both user name and password. This site is 2.52.

It there a security setting that has changed between 2.5 and 2.7, and if so can I change  it, especially durning the development stage while I am in development mode. I would most likely change it back when I turn it over to the client. I have looked but to no avail.

Thanks, making me crazy.

Comment: Do you see a "Remember Me" checkbox on CP login screen?

Comment: There is no "Remember Me" on CP Login Screen. Can you turn one on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Control Panel Session type to Cookies Only: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html

This will get a Remember Me checkbox showing on the login screen.

Comment: That worked great.

Comment: Please select my answer as correct if it helped.